# Changing text on a file using scripts

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing, text

I want to change the PASS_MIN_DAYS = (whatever value is set) to PASS_MIN_DAYS = 15 using a script.The file it's in is /etc/login.defs.

Answer (score 3):

I’d use `sed` like this:

```
sed '/^PASS_MIN_DAYS/s/[0-9]\+/15/'
```

This replaces the number in the line beginning with “PASS_MIN_DAYS” with `15`. To edit the file in place leaving a backup with the `.bak` extension, use the following command. By default you need root access to edit the file.

```
sed -i.bak '/^PASS_MIN_DAYS/s/[0-9]\+/15/' /etc/login.defs
```